# Removing duplicates in array in javaScript using hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, arrays, hasownproperty

I have an array with duplicate elements. While trying to remove duplicate elements using `hasOwnProperty` getting one duplicate element in array rest of duplicate element removed successfully. expexted output = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7] but getting something [1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].  I can use different function and remove duplicates but I'm not understanding why element 3 is coming twice.

```
var array = [1,3,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,3,5,6,4,3]
let output = []

function removeDuplicates(array){

for(let item of array){
    
    if(!output.hasOwnProperty(item))
      output.push(item)
}

return output

}
console.log(removeDuplicates(array));
```

Comment: `hasOwnProperty()` checks if the property (i.e., index in arrays_ exists. Not if an item is present in array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hasOwnProperty checks whether an object contains a given key. The correct way to check if an array contains an element is to use `includes`:

```
if(!output.includes(item))
  output.push(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), you can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var array = [1,3,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,3,5,6,4,3]
let output = []

function removeDuplicates(array){

for(let item of array){
    
    if(!output.includes(item))
      output.push(item)
}

return output

}
console.log(removeDuplicates(array));
```